ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '$4,000.00
car_sales["Price"] = car_sales["Price"].str.replace('[\$\,]|\.\d*', '').astype(int)

I am trying to convert a price to integer using the code above and it is showing error
car_sales["Price"] = car_sales["Price"].str.replace('[\$\,]|\.\d*', '').astype(int)


Note that by erasing the decimal point, you're losing flexibility in your formatting.  The prices can't be in dollars without cents, or in 10ths of a cent.

The only thing that needs to be removed is $. Replacing the separators with assumed ones solves nothing and makes it far more likely to cause incorrect parsing. Remove $ and use the correct locale during parsing instead. There's absolutely no guarantee that , is the thousand instead of the decimal separator, or vice versa. That's how those £100K electricity bill errors are created

Where does the data come from? You'll avoid the entire problem if you tell Pandas what locale or format to use in eg read_csv

Your regular expression is incorrect. Also, as you're using a regular expression, you have to tell replace() that that's your intention
import pandas as pd

d = {
    "Price": ["$4,000.00"]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)

df["Price"] = df["Price"].str.replace(r"[$\.,]", "", regex=True).astype(int)
print(df)

Output:
    Price
0  400000

Observation:
It seems unlikely that you really want to remove the dot and that what you really want is:
df["Price"] = df["Price"].str.replace(r"[$,]", "", regex=True).astype(float)

